# css3 columns + responsive layouts: animate item position changes.using css3 or jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transition, multiple-columns

I'm creating a masonry style layout but with css3 for the columns instead as it allowed me to build the layout with greater ease and much more precisely, especially since I'm building a responsive layout.

Now, I'm using css3 media queries to change the amount of columns displayed based on the size of the window. What I want to do is animate the change in position of the elements of the columns between columns when the number of columns change as the window is resized.

Here is some of my css code:

```
@media all and (min-width: 961px) and (max-width: 1599px){
    #portfolio {
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        -moz-column-count:4;
        -moz-column-gap:3px;
        -webkit-column-count:4;
        -webkit-column-gap:3px;
        column-count:4;
        column-gap:3px;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1600px){
    #portfolio {
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        -moz-column-count:5;
        -moz-column-gap:3px;
        -webkit-column-count:5;
        -webkit-column-gap:3px;
        column-count:5;
        column-gap:3px;
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to approach this? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

See animation-property:

```
/* Animation Property */
animation-property: width;
animation-property: height;
transition-duration: 1s;
/* webkit */
-webkit-animation-property: width;
-webkit-animation-property: height;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
/* moz */
-moz-animation-property: width;
-moz-animation-property: height;
-moz-transition-duration: 1s;
/* opera */
-o-animation-property: width;
-o-animation-property: height;
-o-transition-duration: 1s;
```

Example: http://theboywhocriedfox.com/demo/animate-transitions-with-media-queries/

Comment: This does not work with the `columns` property. It only works when you explicitly change the `width` or `height`.